# 2 AJAX call on a single ejs page

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, ejs

I have a page which has 2 AJAX call, lets say /api1 and /api2.

/api1 renders a page using ejs engine and this page has a button on click of which /api2 gets called, which should open a modal/popup window.

Although the popup gets opened but it displays the data of /api1 only not of /api2.

Pseudo Code is as follows :

```js
$("#my_button").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      url: '/api2',
      method:'GET',
      data:{fieldname:'<%= data.fieldname %>'},
      success: function(dataFromapi2){
        $("#myModal").modal("show");
        $("#myTable").html('<table class="table table-bordered">'+
          '<thead><tr>' +
          '<th>Name</th>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '</thead>'+
        '<tbody>'+

        '<tr>'+
          '<td><%= dataFromapi2.name %></td>'+
          '</tr>'+
          '</tbody>'+
          '</table>'
        );
      },
      error: function (error) {
        $('#process_status').html(error);
      }
    });
  });
```

```html
<div class="abc">
 <!-- Diplaying the data of /api1 using <%= data.fieldname %>  -->
 <button class="btn" id="my_button" name="my_button">
 
 
 <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!--Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body">
          <fieldset>
            <div id="myTable" class="table-responsive">
              
            </div>
          </fieldset>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 
</div>
```

Above code is present in a single ejs file (sample.ejs), which gets rendered on call of /api1.

When /api2 gets called, it returns me correct response on browser console, but while using that response inside ejs tags (<% %>), it returns me an error (dataFromapi2 is not defined.)

Comment: You should provide your code for others to solve this issue

Comment: Are you using different variables for your XMLHttpRequests?

Comment: @Anuresh : Added code snipped, it should help now in better understading.

Answer (score 0):

Your jQuery ajax call appears to be calling api2, which is what you want. If your view is seeing the results of api1 instead of api2, then I suggest checking your server configuration starting with the router. After that, verify the controllers are behaving correctly by using a `curl http://localhost/api2` directly on the server. If that still doesn't work, then you must have something wrong with `dataFromapi2.name`. Without further information, it will be difficult to debug your problem.

Comment: I double checked my server configuration and it seems to be pointing in correct direction. Even Postman returns me a correct response for /api2.

I am still confused over using dataFromapi2 inside ejs tags. To rephrase my question :
I cannot access dataFromapi2 inside ejs tags, and the only variable that is accessible inside ejs tags is data. Is it expected behavior?

Comment: Your ajax request looks odd. Look at this: `data:{fieldname:'<%= data.fieldname %>'},` How is the server supposed to know you want `dataFromapi2.name`? Can you post the exact curl request that you used to verify your api2?

Comment: Alex, this particular line `data:{fieldname:'<%= data.fieldname %>'}` is used to fetch the fieldname from the response of /api1 (i.e. from where this page is getting rendered) and send it to /api2 as a GET parameter.
Success handler of /api2 ajax call catches `dataFromapi2` and the same is being used in ejs tags.